# pagination in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I want to add pagination to sample table 'passenger'.I have downloaded pagination package by    `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` .In my controller code I have added paginate function.table displays one row but pagination controller is not shown (<<1 2 3>>).I want to show pagination control. How can I get pagination control.

Contrller travelApprovalController

```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use DB;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

   class travelApprovalController extends Controller {
   public function index(){
   $users = DB::table('passenger')->paginate(1);
   return view('approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
   }
  }
```

approval_view.vlade.php

```
 <table border = 1>
     <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Passanger Name</td>
        <td>Destination</td>
        <td>Created Date</td>
     </tr>
     @foreach ($users as $user)
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->p_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->p_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->destination }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->created_date }}</td>
    </tr>
     @endforeach
  </table>
```

web.php (route)

```
Route::get('view-records','travelApprovalController@index');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border = 1>
     <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Passanger Name</td>
        <td>Destination</td>
        <td>Created Date</td>
     </tr>
     @foreach ($users as $user)
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->p_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->p_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->destination }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->created_date }}</td>
    </tr>
     @endforeach
     {{$users->links()}}
  </table>
```